# Use Ack on chunked responses with Spray

Tags: scala, spray

I'm using spray-can 1.2.1.

I'm streaming big files from/to a storage, I use both chunked requests and chunked responses for that.

For chunk requests I use the built-in ack mechanism in my actor to make sure each chunk has been written before sending more:

```
connection ! MessageChunk(data).withAck(ChunkSent)
```

`connection` is the IO actor provided by Spray and Akka, then I can wait for a `ChunkSent` before sending the next chunk. Good.

I'm struggling to reproduce the same behavior with chunked responses. I can send my `HttpRequest` and then receive a `ChunkedResponseStart`, followed by a bunch of `MessageChunk`s and finally a `ChunkedMessageEnd` but is there a way to force Spray to wait for **me** to send an ack after each `MessageChunk` before sending the next one?

Edit: Just to be a bit more clear: I use spray-can as a client in this case, I am not the server, the server is the storage I mentioned before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well put question. Currently, you cannot make spray (1.x.1) wait for Acks before continuing to read.

What you can do however is to send `Tcp.SuspendReading` and `Tcp.ResumeReading` commands to the client connection (sender of chunks) to instruct the Akka IO TCP layer to stop reading while you are overloaded. See this [proof-of-concept](https://github.com/jrudolph/spray/commit/e707a2d7b99cd2355a76d6c2a80de040a59a59c3) which tries to add Acking for the receive side (for the server but should work similarly for the client side) on top of `SuspendReading/ResumeReading` for hints about how to build something with the current version of spray.

This situation is clearly not optimal because especially under load 1) you need to figure out that you are overloaded and 2) those message may be stuck in the message queue of the TCP connection before they will be handled.

There are two things that will improve the situation in the future:

- Since recently Akka IO supports a "pull mode" where the TCP connection will only ever read once and then wait for a `Tcp.ResumeReading` command (basically an Ack). However, this is not available for use in spray (and probably won't be).
- What we are focusing on right now for Akka HTTP is streaming support. The plan is to introduce a new API (next to what we have in spray-can) that makes working with streams natural for HTTP and which will support automatic back-pressure support without any need for extra user code to support it. Alas, it is not yet ready.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. A few questions: what level of Spray API supports Tcp.SuspendReading/ResumeReading? Connection/Host/Request? Could you explain your point 2): "message may be stuck in the message queue of the TCP connection before they will be handled." not quite sure I understand the implications here, does it mean that there is a risk of losing a chunk? Looking forward to the new API :)

Comment: 1) I think each of them should support them though I haven't tried. It should work if you send `Tcp.SuspendReading` to the sender `ActorRef` which sent you a `MessageChunk` (which is spray's internal HTTP connection actor)

Comment: 2) The `Tcp.SuspendReading` mechanism must first reach the Akka IO network level before it has any effect. In the meantime Akka IO may already read lots of data from the network which might increase memory pressure on your JVM heap etc. which in turn might additionally delay the `Tcp.SuspendReading` message from reaching the Akka IO connection actor and be handled. I haven't really reproduced such a scenario but it is at least imaginable.

Comment: Wrt 2) this means in consequence, that `Tcp.SuspendReading` probably works if the source of backpressure is a slow disk to which you write the response data but do so slower than the data arrives. However, if the source of backpressure is too much CPU load or the JVM heap is almost full, the aforementioned scenario could arise and the situation might escalate itself and `Tcp.SuspendReading` may come too late to have an effect.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I started experimenting `Tcp.SuspendReading` and I did see the delay before it takes effect. I will give it a try anyway, see if it helps.